# Can ImageView in android.widget.Gallery be framed with a View that includes picture title below?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am interested in using the Horizontal Gallery widget. I know how to put a selected frame around the ImageView but can I put the ImageView inside a larger view and have say a TextView above and below? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom adapter and inflate a custom view which contains the imageView and textview
Refer: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/android-gallery-view-without-pictures.html